# Find if part of a string is within a Dataframe in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Kind of a confusing question, but I'll explain it thoroughly.

Here is dataframe 1

| ID | Name | Letter | Range |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16x019CF123 | Mike | Aasd | 12134 |
| EMU_x123FF2 | Lye | BASD | 21231 |
| SAT_xFF314C | Rike | GSDAS | 21341 |

Dataframe 2

| Index | ID |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 019CF123 |
| 1 | 123FF2 |
| 2 | FF314C |

So now I have 2 Panda Datframes

ID in DF2 corresponds to ID in DF1, however not fully.

ID in DF1    |ID in DF2

16x019CF123 | 019CF123 (Notice that the ID in DF2 is just everything after "x" in DF1)

Now, here is what I need to do.

I need to extract entire rows with the ID's from DF 1 which are NOT in DF 2

Hope I made it as clear as I can.

Answer (score 1):

You can `extract` the ID after the 'x' (here using a regex, but you could also split on 'x' and take the last item) and check if the value `isin` the reference column. Finally use this info (that is a Series of booleans) to slice the initial dataframe, after inverting the condition (to get "**not** in"):

```
df1[~df1['ID'].str.extract('(?<=x)(.*$)').isin(df2['ID'])]
```

If you want to better understand how this works, here is a version with intermediate variables, you can print them to see the steps:

```
clean_ID = df1['ID'].str.extract('(?<=x)(.*$)')
mask = clean_ID.isin(df2['ID'])
df3 = df1[~mask]
```